# Where are Drivechain votes computed?

Tags: coinbase-transaction, sidechains, drivechains

In the context of the Drivechain proposal, for UTXOs in miner-controlled escrows to be spent, they have to be voted on by each block over a large number of blocks, right?

Now, how are these votes made and where are they computed? I think the votes are somehow written in the block coinbase, but how exactly? It's not like there's much space there. And then each full node has to keep a table of what transaction has how many votes and verify against that whenever a transaction is included in the block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **votes** are published on the block coinbase. This can be done in multiple ways, some more efficient than others. The BIP-300 specification proposes a way that is somewhat complex but tries to be efficient.

The **actual current count** at any point -- i.e. the sum of all upvotes and downvotes -- is computed from these coinbase votes and kept by all nodes as a part of the chainstate. Again, the actual physical place of where these things are kept is an *implementation detail* (they could be either kept in a separate table or somewhere associated with the UTXO that is holding the Drivechain funds).